# find out if a command is included in folders of environment variable PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, environment-variables

I cannot find out how to see if a command is included in folders of environment variable `PATH`. I tried the command:

```
$type -t $command
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
if [[ $(type -p command) ]]; then
echo "Found"
else
echo "Not Found"
fi
```

You can use `-t` too (See exceptions at bottom.).

Or (only testing the exit status with `type`):

```
if type command >& /dev/null; then 
echo "Found"
else
echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Note: See exceptions at bottom.

Another solution (using `hash`):

```
if [[ ! $(hash command 2>&1) ]]; then
echo "Found"
else
echo "Not Found"
fi
```

Note: See exceptions at bottom.

> Exceptions:

```
type command
type help
hash command
hash help
type -t command
type -t help
```

`command` and `help` are bash built-ins, they are not in any path in PATH environment variable. So the other methods except the first one (with `-p` option) will Print out **Found** for bash built-in commands which are not in any path in environment PATH variable.

Better use the first method (with `-p` option) if you only want to check if it's located in the paths in PATH environment variable.

Or if you want to use `type -t` then change the if statement like this:

```
if [[ $(type -t command) == file ]]; then
```

Comment: Instead of capturing the output of `type`, just test the exit status: `if ! type command >& /dev/null; then` (the output redirection suppresses any output `type` itself might produce).

Comment: `type command >& /dev/null` is always true, thus your `if` statement will always be skipped.. @chepner

Comment: In Bash, maybe also look at `hash`, which returns nonzero if the command you supply as an argument cannot be found.

Comment: "type returns true if
              any of the arguments are found, false if none are found."

Comment: @chepner That's true, but `if ! type command >& /dev/null; then` doesn't work, because it's sending non empty string (bash: command not found) to `/dev/null` when false. So basically `type command >& /dev/null` is always true in this if statement..

Comment: @chepner For ex: run this: `[[ ! $(type command >& /dev/null) ]] && echo found`, No matter what you put in `command` the output will always be `found`.

Comment: Why are you capturing the output at all? Just test its exit status.

Comment: @chepner That will print unnecessary output which isn't expected in if else testing...

Comment: That's why I redirect both standard error and standard output to /dev/null with >&. I am ignoring any visible output and looking only at the exit status.

Comment: @chepner It seems I misunderstood, sorry for the mistake, I will add your solution to my answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean looking at your path? Similar to:

```
$ set | grep PATH
```

---

Oh, now I understand. Checking for an executable in the path is fairly easy. I usually use something like the following:

```
## test for exe in PATH or exit
exevar="$(which exe 2>/dev/null)"
[ x = x$exevar ] && { echo "'exe' not in path"; exit 1; }

## exe in path, continue
echo "exevar = $exevar"
```

or use `type -p` to eliminate the call to `which`

```
## test for exe in PATH or exit
exevar="$(type -p exe 2>/dev/null)"
[ x = x$exevar ] && { echo "'exe' not in path"; exit 1; }

## exe in path, continue
echo "exevar = $exevar"
```

Comment: hey David, I just want to make an if instruction. EG                                      if ($command included in PATH) --> continue with the scripting                          else quit. do you understand?